# How to set resolution for modularity in python-igraph?

Tags: python, igraph, networkx, gephi

I have a graph G in pajek .net format, which I read using igraph and use community detection using Louvain method. But I want to be able to manually change the resolution to see how the modularity changes and subsequently, how clusters change.

I can change the resolution in gephi before calculating the modularity. Is that possible, if so- how? I'm also open to using networkx if this is possible in networkx.

Answer (score 1):

[`igraph.Graph.community_multilevel(self, weights=None, return_levels=False)`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_multilevel) has a `return_levels` parameter. If `True`, the communities at each level are returned in a list. So each element in this list will be a clustering that corresponds to a different "resolution" (i.e. level) of Louvain.

---

For example, Louvain produces two levels when clustering the karate club graph

```
import igraph as ig
import networkx as nx
# networkx is only needed to load the karate club graph

karate = igraph.Graph.Adjacency((nx.to_numpy_matrix(nx.karate_club_graph()) > 0).tolist(),
                                 mode = igraph.ADJ_UNDIRECTED)
clusterings = igraph.Graph.community_multilevel(karate, return_levels=True)
```

where `clusterings[0]` is the first level and `clusterings[1]` the second. `clusterings[0]` will be a finer resolution than `clusterings[1]`, which can be seen in this case as `clusterings[0]` contained more communities

```
>>> # number of communities in the first level is given by
>>> max(clusterings[0].membership) + 1
6
>>> # number of communities in the second level is given by
>>> max(clusterings[1].membership) + 1
4
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `igraph.Graph.community_multilevel` does not expose the resolution parameter. `networkx` does not have the Louvain method implemented natively, but there is the excellent `community` package that builds on top of `networkx`, and which allows you to set the resolution parameter. [Bitbucket repository here](https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain) or `pip install python-louvain`).